# How do I use exchangelib to connect to work email that uses Outlook Web App (OWA)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am currently trying to find ways to connect to my work email through a language and python seems to have a library I am looking for. I found the exchangelib library but it is a bit older and I couldn't find anything else to connect to an Exchange Server (my work email aren't "@outlook.com").

I found my username ("WORD\username") and I know my email, password, and the url for the outlook web app email ("www.company.net")

```py
from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE, Folder


def connect(SERVER, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    """
    Get Exchange account cconnection with server
    """
    creds = Credentials(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    config = Configuration(server=SERVER, credentials=creds)
    account = Account(primary_smtp_address=EMAIL,  config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:2]:
        print(item.subject, item.body, item.attachments)


def main():

    print(connect("www.company.net",
                  "my@email.net", "WORD\\username", "password"))
```

This is just supposed to print emails I have but I can't seem to connect because the host fails to respond

```py
Failed to create cached protocol with key ('https://www.company.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx', Credentials('WORD\\username', '********')): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.company.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /EWS/Exchange.asmx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000169BAF68FD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

I tried using the complete url for my OWA email and used exchangelib service_endpoint parameter instead

```py
def connect(SERVER, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD):
    """
    Get Exchange account cconnection with server
    """
    creds = Credentials(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
    config = Configuration(service_endpoint=SERVER, credentials=creds)
    account = Account(primary_smtp_address=EMAIL,  config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:2]:
        print(item.subject, item.body, item.attachments)
```

but it fails to get authorization type

```py
Failed to create cached protocol with key ('https://company.net/.../.../', Credentials('WORD\\username', '********')): Failed to get auth type from service
```

Is there something I am missing? Could it be because of a security feature on my company's side? I am not sure how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

exchangelib uses EWS to connect to the Exchange server. OWA is just a web-based client for Exchange. You cannot connect to it programmatically. Still, it's entirely possible that your server has an EWS endpoint you can connect to.

You need to either enable autodiscover to find the EWS endpoint automatically, or ask your Exchange server admins for the correct endpoint for EWS.